# Where Ish (איש) comes from and how Adam became Ish?

Tags: names, parashat-bereishit, adam

Adam is called Adam through the whole Torah (I think) except for one time where he calls his wife Ishah to dignify that she was taken from Ish ([Ber 2.23](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.2.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)):

> וַיֹּאמֶר הָאָדָם זֹאת הַפַּעַם עֶצֶם מֵעֲצָמַי וּבָשָׂר מִבְּשָׂרִי לְזֹאת יִקָּרֵא אִשָּׁה כִּי מֵאִישׁ לֻקֳחָה־זֹּאת׃
>
> Then the man said, “This one at last Is bone of my bones And flesh of my flesh. This one shall be called Woman, For from man was she taken.”

Where does this name/title/designation Ish come from - did G-d call him so, did he realize that name on his own?